# What is the most efficient way to correct text type data in a column?

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, factors

```
fito <- c("forest", "savaaaana", "brae soil", "bare soil", "savanna", "froest")
id <- 1:6

df <- data.frame(fito = as.factor(fito), id = id)
```

What is the smartest way to replace the wrong typed data `("savaaaana", "brae soil", "froest")` with the correct data `("savanna", "bare soil", "forest")`?

At the beginning I have six factors. The correct is to have only three.

How can I do this using the tidyverse package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df2 <- df %>% mutate(fito = fct_collapse(fito, savanna = c("savaaaana", "savanna"),
                                 `bare soil` = c("brae soil","bare soil"),
                                 forest = c("forest","froest" )))
 
str(df2)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ fito: Factor w/ 3 levels "bare soil","forest",..: 2 3 1 1 3 2
 $ id  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

old<- c("savaaaana", "brae soil", "froest") 
new<- c("savanna", "bare soil", "forest")
df %>%
   mutate(fito=factor(str_replace_all(fito, set_names(new, old))))
 
      fito id
1    forest  1
2   savanna  2
3 bare soil  3
4 bare soil  4
5   savanna  5
6    forest  6

df %>%
 mutate(fito = lift(fct_recode)(as.list(set_names(old, new)), fito))

       fito id
1    forest  1
2   savanna  2
3 bare soil  3
4 bare soil  4
5   savanna  5
6    forest  6

df %>%
  mutate(fito = invoke(fct_recode, c(list(fito),as.list(set_names(old, new)))))
       fito id
1    forest  1
2   savanna  2
3 bare soil  3
4 bare soil  4
5   savanna  5
6    forest  6
```